# Can You Get Latitude and Longitude From A Database for MapKit in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, mapkit

I am working on a SwiftUI project and want to place a map in a view that uses coordinates stored in Firestore. Apple's example for MapKit in SwiftUI uses static latitude and longitude parameters in the @State property and then binds the property to the Map() view.

```
struct BusinessMapView: View {
    @State private var region: MKCoordinateRegion = {
        var mapCoordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 44.621754, longitude: -66.475873)
        var mapZoomLevel = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 5.00, longitudeDelta: 5.00)
        var mapRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: mapCoordinates, span: mapZoomLevel)
        return mapRegion
    }()
            
    var body: some View {
        Map(coordinateRegion: $region)
    }
}
```

What I want to do is the following but clearly this is not allowed since you cannot access other properties in another property.

```
struct BusinessMapView: View {
    @ObservedObject var businessAddressRowViewModel: BusinessAddressRowViewModel

    @State private var region: MKCoordinateRegion = {
        var mapCoordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: businessAddressRowViewModel.businessAddress.latitude, longitude: businessAddressRowViewModel.businessAddress.longitude)
        var mapZoomLevel = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 5.00, longitudeDelta: 5.00)
        var mapRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: mapCoordinates, span: mapZoomLevel)
        return mapRegion
    }()
            
    var body: some View {
        Map(coordinateRegion: $region)
    }
}
```

So my question is, is there a way to set the coordinates from a database for a Map() in SwiftUI or is the only option to use static values for latitude and longitude?

EDIT ADDED FOR MORE INFORMATION

```
class BusinessAddressRowViewModel: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    
    // Properties
    var id: String = ""
    
    public static let shared = BusinessAddressRowViewModel()
    
    // Published Properties
    @Published var businessAddress: BusinessAddress
    
    // Combine Cancellable
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    
    // Initializer
    init(businessAddress: BusinessAddress) {
        self.businessAddress = businessAddress
        self.startCombine()
    }
    
    // Starting Combine
    func startCombine() {
        // Get Bank Account
        $businessAddress
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .compactMap { businessAddress in
                businessAddress.id
            }
            .assign(to: \.id, on: self)
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}
```

The shared property gives an error stating the parameter businessAddress is missing.

The data is coming from Firebase Firestore here.

```
class BusinessAddressRepository: ObservableObject {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    private var snapshotListener: ListenerRegistration?
    
    @Published var businessAddresses = [BusinessAddress]()
    
    init() {
        startSnapshotListener()
    }
        
    func startSnapshotListener() {
        // Get the currentUserUid
        guard let currentUserId = Auth.auth().currentUser else {
            return
        }
        
        if snapshotListener == nil {
            // Add a SnapshotListener to the BusinessAddress Collection.
            self.snapshotListener = db.collection(FirestoreCollection.users).document(currentUserId.uid).collection(FirestoreCollection.businessAddresses).addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
                // Check to see if an error occured and print it. IMPLEMENT ERROR HANDLING LATER
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error getting documents: \(error)")
                } else {
                    print("BusinessAddressRepository - snapshotListener called")
                    
                    // Check to make sure the Collection contains Documents
                    guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                        print("No Business Addresses.")
                        return
                    }
                    
                    // Documents exist.
                    self.businessAddresses = documents.compactMap { businessAddress in
                        do {
                            return try businessAddress.data(as: BusinessAddress.self)
                        } catch {
                            print(error)
                        }
                        return nil
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func stopSnapshotListener() {
        if snapshotListener != nil {
            snapshotListener?.remove()
            snapshotListener = nil
        }
    }
}
```

Data is being passed to BusinessAddressRowViewModel from the BusinessAddressViewModel. BusinessAddressView holds the list that creates all the rows.

```
class BusinessAddressViewModel: ObservableObject {
    var businessAddressRepository: BusinessAddressRepository

    // Published Properties
    @Published var businessAddressRowViewModels = [BusinessAddressRowViewModel]()
    
    // Combine Cancellable
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
        
    // Intitalizer
    init(businessAddressRepository: BusinessAddressRepository) {
        self.businessAddressRepository = businessAddressRepository
        self.startCombine()
    }
    
    // Starting Combine - Filter results for business addresses created by the current user only.
    func startCombine() {
        businessAddressRepository
            .$businessAddresses
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .map { businessAddress in
                businessAddress
                    .map { businessAddress in
                        BusinessAddressRowViewModel(businessAddress: businessAddress)
                    }
            }
            .assign(to: \.businessAddressRowViewModels, on: self)
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}
```

Comment: The code above in the second block does not compile. It throws an error. Since region references businessCoordinates it’s not allowed. My question is how you can use region with data from a database of you can’t reference other properties like businessCoordinates.

Answer (score 0):

You have an initialization problem here, having nothing to do with the Map(). You are trying to use `businessCoordinates` the instantiated `ObservedObject` variable in the initializer, and, I am sure, are getting a `Cannot use instance member 'businessCoordinates' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available` error.

If you don't need 'businessCoordinates' anywhere in the view, other than the data, I would recommend this:

```
class BusinessCoordinates: ObservableObject {
    
    public static let shared = BusinessCoordinates()
...
}
```

This will give you a `Singleton` you can use at will. Then you use it like this:

```
struct BusinessMapView: View {
    @State private var region: MKCoordinateRegion

    init() {
        let mapCoordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: BusinessCoordinates.shared.latitude, longitude: BusinessCoordinates.shared.longitude)
        var mapZoomLevel = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 5.00, longitudeDelta: 5.00)
        _region = State(initialValue: MKCoordinateRegion(center: mapCoordinates, span: mapZoomLevel))

    }
            
    var body: some View {
        Map(coordinateRegion: $region)
    }
}
```

Comment: While I like this approach I am not sure it will work for my application. I've updated the question above to show the current BusinessCoordinates file. Since the file is the View Model for a Row View I am feeding the VM with a business address. This means I have to initiate the shared property with a business address. I don't know how this would be possible.

Comment: You put it in `BusinessAddressRowViewModel`, but in the `MapView` you are using a `BusinessCoordinates` as the `ObservedObject`. Where did this come from?

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion. I renamed the file in the original post try and simplify things. I've changed the naming of the ObservedObject to match the file name.

Comment: Where is the data coming from? Leaving your map view out of this, how do you get data into `BusinessAddressRowViewModel`? And what holds that data before you instantiate `BusinessAddressRowViewModel`?

Comment: I added the repository file which pulls the data from Firebase Firestore and the BusinessAddressViewModel that creates the BusinessAddressRowViewModels.

Comment: You seem to have 3 view models, 1 another that contains the third. It should all be in 1. When you need a type, make it a struct that is managed in the view model. Your life will be much easier. Essentially, `BusinessAddressRepository` remains the ObserveableObject, and `BusinessAddressViewModel` becomes an `@Published` struct `BusinessAddress`, etc.

Comment: Can you point me to an example of this architecture? I've never seen it done this way, however I am open.

Comment: It is MVVM architecture. You just have a complicated interrelated model that it making things more difficult. in SwiftUI, you should be using mostly structs and very few classes. A struct as a variable in a class works very well. You don't need to use a class in that instance. Just move your logic into one mode classl and define your structs as you need.